# `if` statement issues

Tags: c#, if-statement

I've made a small speed citation form for my class that calculates predetermined fields and adds them to the users speed.

For example, if the user selects visitor the minimum citation is #25 dollars if the infraction happened at night their is an additional $25 dollar penalty. If student is selected the citation is #35 + additional $2 per every mile over, unless Sophomore is selected than it becomes $5.

Unfortunately, IF statements are my bane and I've made a mistake with my IF statements because my math isn't coming out correctly. If I select a student + night + 25 in a 20 that total should equal 70 and I am getting 10.

GUI Image: http://postimg.org/image/doy6n0sp3/

Edit: I ended up re-writing the code to resolve the issues I had

Comment: Please add a clear example of UI input, current output and expected output.

Comment: Debug through your code and see where the mismatch happening.

Comment: You really ought to learn to use the debugger and step through your code. You'll be able to see quite clearly where your logic falls down.

Comment: Well you always add either the sophomore or fresheman fine based on `SophCB.Checked`.  Are you missing an `else if(FreshCB.Checked)`?  Or should there first be a `If(StudentCB.Checked)`?

Comment: Are you sure your initial variables are correct? In your text, you wrote that the initial fine for a visitor is 25 but you initialized the variable `visitorFine` to 35. Same mistake for `studentFine`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would also suggest nesting your IF statements if you wish to charge ONLY the students $2 or $5 respectively.

```
        if (VisitorRB.Checked)
        {
            ticketPrice = visitorFine ;
        }
        else if (StudentRB.Checked)
        {
            ticketPrice = studentFine;
            if (SophCB.Checked)
            {
                ticketPrice = ticketPrice + sophomoreOver;
            }
            else
            {
                ticketPrice = ticketPrice + freshmenOver;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I feel you mean this

```
sophomoreOver = (double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit) * 5;
freshmenOver = (double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit) * 2;
```

Comment: Yeah that's actually my fault - that error was originally corrected, but accidentally deleted as I attempted to resolve the calculation errors. Having implemented it back, I' m still running into calculation errors though.

Comment: @JasonSmith Can you try debugging through your code line-by-line, and see where you are getting an unexpected behavior?

Comment: Yeah that's what I was just doing, from what I've gathered the soophmore over and freshmenover calls are the problem. If the remove that entire code block the code functions properly. Visitors are charged $25, students $35 and staff $35 + $25 additional at night. I'm not sure what I've done wrong in attempting to calculate a 2 dollar per ever mile over fee, but I've clearly done something wrong if the code works when it isn't implemented.

Comment: @JasonSmith The problem is that if `SophCB` isn't checked you treat all other cases as freshmen.  Is there a check box for freshmen?  If so you need an `else if` not an `else`.

Comment: @JasonSmith Also if this has been corrected you really should update the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why should this:

student + night + 25 in a 20 = 70?

If student = 45 and night = 25 and you add another 25 to that?

Now if you are only saying that you are looking for student + night, then you are correct, but here is a piece of code that is running every time and maybe causing your problem:

```
if (SophCB.Checked)
{
    ticketPrice = ticketPrice + sophomoreOver;
}
else
{
    ticketPrice = ticketPrice + freshmenOver; // this is running if you don't select SophCB every time.
}
```

basically ticketPrice will either be:

```
ticketPrice = ticketPrice + sophomoreOver;
```

or

```
ticketPrice = ticketPrice + freshmenOver;
```

Comment: The student fine is 45,  the night fine is 25, so the total is 70.  But you are correct about the sophomore or freshman fine always being applied.

Comment: Yeah and I only wanted those fines to be applied to students. I had a typo in my math text, vs my code text. I was trying to say for example, a student would face a base fine of $45 it at night +25 would be added, so yeah $70. If they were a freshmen cause doing 30 in a 25 then they could face an extra $10 fee since 5 * 2 is 10 making the grand total 80

Comment: @JasonSmith So, you have a check box for sophomore and one for student, but do you not have one for freshman?  If not, it seems  like you need one.

Answer (score 0):

One error I see in your code is missing braces. The `*` will be executed before the `-`.

Replace

```
sophomoreOver = double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit * 5;
freshmenOver = double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit * 2;
```

by

```
sophomoreOver = ( double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit ) * 5;
freshmenOver = ( double.Parse(SpeedtextBox.Text) - speedLimit ) * 2;
```